# Extract words from multiple strings using AWK/SED

Tags: awk, sed, xml

I am looking for logic where in I am trying to extract words from multiple lines using AWK command in Linux
Tried in multiple ways with AWK and SED but no results.

Attached [image]is the text file and expected output

Comment: Please, [don't post images of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text).  Since it's a short text file, just copy and paste the text.

Comment: I tried doing so, but it is skipping lot of characters in the file

Comment: Well, that just means that we can't actually _test_ our solutions against the data that you actually have, which is pretty bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this to get the desired output

```
$ echo "DEVICE-NAME STATUS" ; grep -e NAME -e STATUS <filename> | sed 's#NAME##g ; s#STATUS##g ;  s#<>## ; s#</>##' | xargs -L2 | column -t
```

**Output:**

```
DEVICE-NAME STATUS
METASYNC Online
DELTA OFFLINE
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, but I am getting below error

awk: warning: escape sequence `\*' treated as plain `*'

updated my query, please go through it once.

Comment: I have updated my answer , please check if it works now

Comment: Sorry, it is giving only  DEVICE-NAME STATUS in output

Comment: You are using your filename in `$ echo "DEVICE-NAME STATUS" ; grep -e NAME -e STATUS <filename> | awk -F "\\\\*\\\\*" '{print $2}' |   xargs -L2 echo` ? right ??  if yes , please give output of `$ echo "DEVICE-NAME STATUS" ; grep -e NAME -e STATUS <filename>`

Comment: yes I am using devicelog.txt
output:

<NAME>METASYNC</NAME>
<STATUS>Online</STATUS>
<NAME>DELTA</NAME>
<STATUS>Online</STATUS>

Comment: I have edited my aswer, please check, it should work now , i was confused with the ** symbols in unedited question that you posted

Answer (score 1):

Using [XMLStarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/):

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -m '//APPLIANCE' -v 'concat(NAME/text()," ",STATUS/text())' -nl file.xml
```

For the given data, this would produce

```
METASYNC Online
DELTA Offline
```

It does this by finding all `APPLIANCE` nodes in the XML document and concatenating the values of their `NAME` and `STATUS` sub-nodes with a space in-between.  The `-nl` at the end inserts a newline after outputting the result for each `APPLIANCE`.

If you want column headers and nicer tabular format:

```
( echo 'Device_name Status'
  xmlstarlet ...as above... ) | column -t
```